# Laravel 5.2 Authentication Redirect with Parameters

Tags: laravel, knockout.js, laravel-5

Since, I was not able to find any question like this in SO, I am writing this post hoping this is not a duplicate...

I have a page developed using **KnockoutJs** which I am using to protect via Laravel Authentication. Basically, **I am using Laravel only for the purpose of login/registration** and once the user logs/signs in, he is redirected to the KnockoutJS page.

Now lets just say I have a URL,

```
http://example.com/mypage#q=some+parameters&p=somethingsomething
```

If I share that URL with one of my friends, it obviously redirects my friend to the Login Page. Now, the login page URL (where he is redirected to) is

```
http://example.com/login#q=some+parameters&p=somethingsomething
```

But once he logs in, he is being redirected to

```
http://example.com/mypage#
```

Which obviously is not right, because I need the parameters to be there...

My **Routes** page is as follows,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', 'MainController@index')->name('home.index');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/mypage', 'MyController@index')->name('mypage.index');
});
```

And my **AuthController** has the **redirectTo** Url set

```
protected $redirectTo = '/mypage';
```

What change should I do (in AuthController, or in Routes? Or in a MiddleWare) to redirect the user to

```
http://example.com/mypage#q=some+parameters&p=somethingsomething
```

after login?

Comment: Kindly search for `Redirect::intended()` (in laravel documentation), cheers. The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being caught by the authentication filter. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

Comment: @Kyslik It's not redirecting me back to that page... It gets me to `http://example.com/mypage#` when I login. Does laravel consider the parameters given after **#** in the url for this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Laravel's `Redirect::intended` did not work for me, I am posting the answer to this question myself...

User **Jquery/Javscript** to create cookies after redirection like this :

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var intended = window.location.hash;
(intended.length > 0) ? jQuery.cookie('intended', '/app' + intended) : jQuery.cookie('intended', '/app');

})();
```

and make these changes into Laravel 5.2's default `AuthController`

```
//Replace the default constructor with this
public function __construct(Request $request) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['intended'])) {
        $this->setRedirect($request);
    }
}

//Copy paste it anywhere in your AuthController Class
protected function setRedirect($request) {
        $intended = (url($_COOKIE['intended']));
        $url['intended'] = $intended;
        $request->session()->put('url', $url);
}
```

Hope this helps someone....

Thanks, :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intended method in Laravel.

eg:

```
 public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
```

This will redirect the user to the intended URL to the login page or if there is no intended URL, then to dashboard.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: It's not redirecting me back to that page... It gets me to `http://example.com/mypage#` when I login. Does laravel consider the parameters given after **#** in the url for this method?

Comment: Yes it will consider. I've tested myself and it's working very well.

Comment: Thanks for all your support... But laravel I believe doesn't support that... I am finally using Javascript Cookies to help me redirect me back to the old page...Thanks anyways :)